# Remove white space on a box using tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm trying to make a box with the same size as the writing, but i don't know how. My code:

```
\documentclass[A4paper, twoside, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5 cm, bottom=3.8 cm, left=2 cm, right=2 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,             
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=cyan}
\urlstyle{same}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tcolorbox}[  enhanced,
                    title=\normalsize{Equipe},
                    breakable,
                    colframe=blue!50!black,
                    colback=white,
                    colbacktitle=blue!5!white,
                    fonttitle=\bfseries,
                    coltitle=black,
                    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,
                    yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
                    boxed title style={boxrule=0.5mm,
                    frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west)
                    -- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
                    -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
                    interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
                    -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
                    -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
                    -- cycle;} }]{
                \begin{center}
                \normalsize{
                    Felipe Gimenez Souza - 11916728\footnote{E-mail: \href{mailto: felipegimenezsouza@usp.br}{felipegimenezsouza@usp.br}}
            
                   \vspace{0.2cm}
            
                    Matheus Fogaça Cichocki - 11809990\footnote{E-mail: \href{mailto: matheuscichocki@usp.br } {matheuscichocki@usp.br}}
            
                   \vspace{0.2cm}
            
                    Lucas Roda Ximenes dos Santos - 11917239\footnote{E-mail: \href{mailto:  lcsximenes@usp.br}{lcsximenes@usp.br}}}
                \end{center}
                }
        \end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[  enhanced,
                    title=\normalsize{Professor},
                    breakable,
                    colframe=blue!50!black,
                    colback=white,
                    colbacktitle=blue!5!white,
                    fonttitle=\bfseries,
                    coltitle=black,
                    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,
                    yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
                    boxed title style={boxrule=0.5mm,
                    frame code={ 
                        \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west)
                        -- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
                        -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; 
                    },
                    interior code={ 
                        \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
                        -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
                        -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
                        -- cycle;
                        } }]{
                \begin{center}
                \normalsize{
                    Felix Guillermo Gonzalez Hernandez
                    }
                \end{center}
                }
        \end{tcolorbox}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And i obtain this result:

[image]

But i want something like that:

[image]

Comment: simply use `text width=3in,` in your definition of the `tcolorbox` -- `\begin{tcolorbox}[  enhanced, text width=3in, ...........,
                    title=\normalsize{Equipe}, 
                    -- cycle;} }]`

Comment: also rather than use `begin{center} ......  end{center}` you could just use `\centering`  with the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a `tcolorbox` uses `\linewidth` as initial size. To my knowledge is not possible to automatically adjust the width to the contents, but you can use `width` and `text width` options to reduce box width.

Following code shows the result with `text width`. In this case a new tcolorbox called `mybox` is declared. This reduces typing. The new tcolorbox has one mandatory parameter, the title, and an optional one. In the example this optional parameter is used to introduce any change to the default `maybox`, like `text width`.

```
\documentclass[A4paper, twoside, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5 cm, bottom=3.8 cm, left=2 cm, right=2 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,             
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=cyan}
\urlstyle{same}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    enhanced,
    title=\normalsize{#2},
    breakable,
    colframe=blue!50!black,
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=blue!5!white,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,
                    yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
    boxed title style={boxrule=0.5mm,
        frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west)
                    -- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
                    -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
        interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
                    -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
                    -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
                    -- cycle;} 
    },
    halign=center,
    center,
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}[text width=8cm]{Equipe}
                    Felipe Gimenez Souza - 11916728\footnote{E-mail: \href{mailto: felipegimenezsouza@usp.br}{felipegimenezsouza@usp.br}}
            
                   \vspace{0.2cm}
            
                    Matheus Fogaça Cichocki - 11809990\footnote{E-mail: \href{mailto: matheuscichocki@usp.br } {matheuscichocki@usp.br}}
            
                   \vspace{0.2cm}
            
                    Lucas Roda Ximenes dos Santos - 11917239\footnote{E-mail: \href{mailto:  lcsximenes@usp.br}{lcsximenes@usp.br}}
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}{Professor}
                    Felix Guillermo Gonzalez Hernandez
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[A4paper, twoside, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5 cm, bottom=3.8 cm, left=2 cm, right=2 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,             
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=cyan}
\urlstyle{same}


\begin{document}
\centering
        \begin{tcolorbox}[  enhanced, text width =3in,
            title=\normalsize{Equipe},
            breakable,
            colframe=blue!50!black,
            colback=white,
            colbacktitle=blue!5!white,
            fonttitle=\bfseries,
            coltitle=black,
            attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,
                yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
            boxed title style={boxrule=0.5mm,
                frame code={ \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west)
                    -- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
                    -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; },
                interior code={ \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
                    -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
                    -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
                    -- cycle;} }]{

                    \centering\normalsize{
                        Felipe Gimenez Souza - 11916728\footnote{E-mail: \href{mailto: felipegimenezsouza@usp.br}{felipegimenezsouza@usp.br}}
                        
                        \vspace{0.2cm}
                        
                        Matheus Fogaça Cichocki - 11809990\footnote{E-mail: \href{mailto: matheuscichocki@usp.br } {matheuscichocki@usp.br}}
                        
                        \vspace{0.2cm}
                        
                        Lucas Roda Ximenes dos Santos - 11917239\footnote{E-mail: \href{mailto:  lcsximenes@usp.br}{lcsximenes@usp.br}}}

            }
        \end{tcolorbox}
        
        \begin{tcolorbox}[  enhanced,  text width=3in,
            title=\normalsize{Professor},
            breakable,
            colframe=blue!50!black,
            colback=white,
            colbacktitle=blue!5!white,
            fonttitle=\bfseries,
            coltitle=black,
            attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-0.25mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2,
                yshifttext=2mm-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
            boxed title style={boxrule=0.5mm,
                frame code={ 
                    \path[tcb fill frame] ([xshift=-4mm]frame.west)
                    -- (frame.north west) -- (frame.north east) -- ([xshift=4mm]frame.east)
                    -- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west) -- cycle; 
                },
                interior code={ 
                    \path[tcb fill interior] ([xshift=-2mm]interior.west)
                    -- (interior.north west) -- (interior.north east)
                    -- ([xshift=2mm]interior.east) -- (interior.south east) -- (interior.south west)
                    -- cycle;
            } }]{
                
                    \centering\normalsize{
                        Felix Guillermo Gonzalez Hernandez
                    
                }
                
            }
        \end{tcolorbox}
        

\end{document}
```